# Pydantic how to create a model with required fields and dynamic fields?

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a dynamic json like:

```json
{
  "ts": 1111111,  // this field is required
  ...             // others are dynamic
}
```

The fields are all dynamic except `ts`. E.g:

```json
{"ts":111,"f1":"aa","f2":"bb"}
```

```json
{"ts":222,"f3":"cc","f4":"dd"}
```

How to declare this model with Pydantic?

```py
class JsonData(BaseModel):
    ts: int
    ...  # and then?
```

Equivalent to typescript:

```
interface JsonData {
  ts: number;
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make every fields as optional with Pydantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699451/make-every-fields-as-optional-with-pydantic)

Comment: No. The fields are all dynamic except `ts`. E.g: `{"ts":111,"f1":"aa","f2":"bb"}`, `{"ts":"f3":"cc","f4":"dd"}`

Comment: Are you sure that you need `Pydantic`? Field names are dynamic, field value types also not determined. Here is no profit of `Pydantic` usage. Just use simple dictionary with simple `if 'ts' in my_dict and type(my_dict['ts']) == int` check

Comment: Yes. I use FastAPI with this model to generate OpenAPI schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Without Type Validation

If type validation doesn't matter then you could use the [`extra` option](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/#options) `allow`:

> `'allow'` will assign the attributes to the model.

```py
class JsonData(BaseModel):
    ts: int

    class Config:
        extra = "allow"
```

This will give:

```py
data = JsonData.parse_raw("""
{
   "ts": 222,
   "f3": "cc",
   "f4": "dd"
}
""")
repr(data)
# "JsonData(ts=222, f4='dd', f3='cc')"
```

And the fields can be accessed via:

```py
print(data.f3)
# cc
```

#### With Type Validation

However, if you could change the request body to contain an object holding the "dynamic fields", like the following:

```json
{
  "ts": 111,
  "fields": {
    "f1": "aa",
    "f2": "bb"
  }
}
```

or

```json
{
  "ts": 222,
  "fields": {
    "f3": "cc",
    "f4": "dd"
  }
}
```

you could use a Pydantic model like this one:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class JsonData(BaseModel):
    ts: int
    fields: dict[str, str] = {}
```

That way, any number of fields could be processed, while the field type would be validated, e.g.:

```py
# No "extra" fields; yields an empty dict:
data = JsonData.parse_raw("""
{
  "ts": "222"
}
""")
repr(data)
# "JsonData(ts=222, fields={})"
```

```py
# One extra field:
data = JsonData.parse_raw("""
{
  "ts": 111,
  "fields": {
    "f1": "aa"
  }
}
""")
repr(data)
# "JsonData(ts=111, fields={'f1': 'aa'})"
```

```py
# Several extra fields:
data = JsonData.parse_raw("""
{
  "ts": 222,
  "fields": {
    "f2": "bb",
    "f3": "cc",
    "f4": "dd"
  }
}
""")
repr(data)
# "JsonData(ts=222, fields={'f2': 'bb', 'f3': 'cc', 'f4': 'dd'})"
```

The fields can be accessed like this:

```py
print(data.fields["f2"])
# bb
```

In this context, you might also want to consider the field types to be [`StrictStr`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#strict-types) as opposed to `str`. When using `str`, other types will get coerced into strings, for example when an integer or float is passed in. This doesn't happen with `StrictStr`.

See also: [this workaround](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/1802).

Comment: But is there any way to make f1-f4 dynamic ? Because it contains so many uncertain fields and I do not limit them just f1-f4.

Comment: @FengYu - I've updated the answer.

Comment: @FengYu - Another update.

Comment: Great, that is what I need. Thanks.