# How to make Pydantic recognize attributes from non-model parent class?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a normal Python class:

```py
class NormalClass:
  a: str
  b: bool
```

I don't want NormalClass to inherit from pydantic.BaseModel class, but I still want another class with the same attributes as NormalClass and it being a Pydantic model. So here's what I try:

```py
class ModelClass(BaseModel, NormalClass):
  pass
```

Unfortunately, when I try to use this ModelClass to validate server response in FastAPI, I always get {}. What happens here?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you cannot expect to inherit the features of a `pydantic` model (including fields) from a class that is not a `pydantic` model.

`a` and `b` in `NormalClass` are class attributes. Although the fields of a `pydantic` model are usually defined as class attributes, that does not mean that *any* class attribute is automatically a field. `NormalClass` is not a `pydantic` model because it does not inherit from `BaseModel`. `ModelClass` has no fields because it does not define any fields by itself and has not inherited any fields from a `pydantic` model.

Comment: Thank you. I solved my problem with a metaclass that copies all the annotations from the parent class, almost exactly like the code in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699451/make-every-fields-as-optional-with-pydantic.

So I believe the root problem is that the child classes in Python don't inherit annotations from the parent classes as I initially thought.