# Make all fields with nested pydantic models optional recursively

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a pydantic model with many fields that are also pydantic models.
I would like to make recursively all fields optional.

For example:

```py
class MyModelE(BaseModel):
   f: float

class MyModelA(BaseModel):
   d: str
   e: MyModelE

class MyModel(BaseModel):
   a: MyModelA
   b: int
```

I would like to have a metaclass or method to make all fields of `MyModel` optional, including fields `a`, `b`, `d`, `e`, and `f`.

The solutions described in this previously asked question only make fields that are non-pydantic models optional.

[Make every fields as optional with Pydantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699451/make-every-fields-as-optional-with-pydantic)

Comment: _"The solutions [...] only make fields that are non-pydantic models optional."_ Are you sure? The meta class solution you linked to works fine for me, regardless of the field type, including fields that are themselves Pydantic models.

Comment: Also, pretty sure you have a typo in your code: `a = MyModelA` probably needs to be `a: MyModelA`. And without `__future__.annotations` those forward referencing type annotations are not going to work.

Comment: Oh, and just noticed `MyModelA` and `MyModelE` aren't even Pydantic models here at all... I'm voting to close this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution for `pydantic v2`.

It naturally uses depth first search down the hierarchy of composition and then with the field info found, it builds models with `required=False` bottom-up towards the top.

Also, it does not use any low level hack that depends on the internal implementation of `pydantic` objects, many of which are changed or not available in `v2`.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model

class MyModelE(BaseModel):
       f: float

class MyModelA(BaseModel):
   d: str
   e: MyModelE

class MyModel(BaseModel):
   a: MyModelA
   b: int

def is_pydantic_model(obj):
    try:
        return issubclass(obj, BaseModel)
    except TypeError:
        return False

def show_hierarchy(Model: BaseModel, indent: int=0):
    for k, v in Model.model_fields.items():
        print(f'{" "*indent}{Model.__name__}.{k}: '
              f'type={getattr(v.annotation, "__name__", v.annotation)}, '
              f'required={v.is_required()}')
        if is_pydantic_model(v.annotation):
            show_hierarchy(v.annotation, indent+2)

def unset_required(Model: BaseModel, name: str=None) -> BaseModel:
    fields = {}
    for k, v in Model.model_fields.items():
        if is_pydantic_model(v.annotation):
            fields[k] = (unset_required(v.annotation), None) 
        else:
            fields[k] = (v.annotation, None) 
    return create_model(name if name is not None else Model.__name__, **fields)

show_hierarchy(MyModel)
print('')
UpdateModel = unset_required(MyModel, name='UpdateModel')
show_hierarchy(UpdateModel)
```

This results in

```
MyModel.a: type=MyModelA, required=True
  MyModelA.d: type=str, required=True
  MyModelA.e: type=MyModelE, required=True
    MyModelE.f: type=float, required=True
MyModel.b: type=int, required=True

UpdateModel.a: type=MyModelA, required=False
  MyModelA.d: type=str, required=False
  MyModelA.e: type=MyModelE, required=False
    MyModelE.f: type=float, required=False
UpdateModel.b: type=int, required=False
```

It can handle a model where the same sub-model is used multiple times at different levels as well.

```
class MyModelE(BaseModel):
   f: float

class MyModelA(BaseModel):
   d: str
   e: MyModelE  # MyModelE

class MyModel(BaseModel):
   a: MyModelA
   b: MyModelE  # MyModelE

MyModel.a: type=MyModelA, required=True
  MyModelA.d: type=str, required=True
  MyModelA.e: type=MyModelE, required=True
    MyModelE.f: type=float, required=True # MyModelE
MyModel.b: type=MyModelE, required=True
  MyModelE.f: type=float, required=True   # MyModelE

UpdateModel.a: type=MyModelA, required=False
  MyModelA.d: type=str, required=False
  MyModelA.e: type=MyModelE, required=False
    MyModelE.f: type=float, required=False # MyModelE
UpdateModel.b: type=MyModelE, required=False
  MyModelE.f: type=float, required=False   # MyModelE
```

Comment: Great answer for avoiding the internal implementation of pydantic