# Define model globally so it can be pickled

Tags: python, pickle, pydantic

AllOptional.py

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def partial_model(model: Type[BaseModel]):
    def make_field_optional(field: FieldInfo, default: Any = None) -> Tuple[Any, FieldInfo]:
        new = deepcopy(field)
        # new.default = default
        new.annotation = Optional[field.annotation]  # type: ignore
        return new.annotation, new
    return_model =  create_model(
        f'Partial{model.__name__}',
        __base__=model,
        __module__=model.__module__,
        **{
            field_name: make_field_optional(field_info)
            for field_name, field_info in model.model_fields.items()
        }
    )
    
    return return_model
```

I used this piece of snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699451/make-every-field-as-optional-with-pydantic/75011200#75011200) to make all fields optional.

Model.py

```
from __future__ import annotations

from datetime import datetime, date
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator, computed_field, Field


class Model(BaseModel):
    A: int = Field(serialization_alias='a')
    B: str = Field(serialization_alias='b')
```

Test_Model.py

```
def test_model(self):

    optional_model = partial_model(Model.Model)
    data={'A':1, 'B':None}
    ep_data = optional_model(**data)

    import dill
    e = dill.pickles(ep_data) # returns false
    pickled_data = pickle.dumps(ep_data) # obviously fails
    el_data = pickle.loads(pickled_data) # ultimate goal1 

    el_validate_data = optional_model.model_validate(el_data) # Final goal, validation should work
```

After tough time, figured out this [issue with create_model](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/4178)

It states

> To pickle a dynamically created model:
>
> the model must be defined globally
> it must provide **module**

I tried setting it in globals() and couldn't get it working. Could someone help me with this?

It throws the following error

```
E _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'models.Model.PartialModel'>:     
attribute lookup PartialModel on models.Model failed
```